# Owner group of /var/www

Tags: ubuntu, unix, user-accounts, file-permissions, chown

If I change the owner of /var/www to ftpgroup

```
sudo chown :ftpgroup /var/www
```

am I going to have other kind of issues ? Or is that ok ?

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: Because I need to assign writing privilegies to my ftp users (which are unix users as well). So, I created a group for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find the only user in nobody (or whatever the group who owns it now is called) is nobody, so no, I don't believe it will cause any issues, unless you added users to the group that currently owns /var/www

Comment: ok, how can I see the current owners of a unix directory ? (both users and groups ?)

Comment: `ls -l /var/` will show everything in /var/ including who owns the folders/files. Also, to see which users are part of a group, look up the file `/etc/group` and it's man page `man group`.